# WebMatrix SendMail additional headers

Tags: email, razor, header, tags, webmatrix

I need to add the following tag to my outgoing emails:

{"X-MC-Template", "testheader"}

the code i currently use to send emails is:

```
var header = new[]{"X-MC-Tags:test"};
try {
    // Send email
    WebMail.Send(to: customerEmail,
        subject: "Test Subject",
        body: customerRequest,
        additionalHeaders: header
    );
}
```

Thanks, Gavin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Send method accepts an `IEnumerable<string>` representing additional headers.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh414138(v=vs.111).aspx

Each string must be of the form "header:value" e.g.

```
var customHeader = new[]{"X-MC-Tags:gavin"};
```

The code that knits the headers into the MailMessage looks for a colon as a separator. Here's the internal TryParseHeader method that the WebMail helper uses:

```
internal static bool TryParseHeader(string header, out string key, out string value)
{
    int pos = header.IndexOf(':');
    if (pos > 0)
    {
        key = header.Substring(0, pos).TrimEnd();
        value = header.Substring(pos + 1).TrimStart();
        return key.Length > 0 && value.Length > 0;
    }
    key = null;
    value = null;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I have tried adding the following variable: var headers = IEnumerable<string>() {"X-MC-Tags", "gavin"};

Comment: And this one: var headers = new List<string>() {"X-MC-Tags", "gavin"};

Comment: and adding the variable to the additional header, but with no luck: additionalHeaders: headers

Comment: Looks like the string has to include a colon: `var header = new[]{"X-MC-Tags:gavin"};`

Comment: Works an absolute treat as usual. I have updated my code above to the working code. As long as you dont see any further issues, then another great answer. Thanks.